# How to make jtable cells uneditable

Tags: java, jtable

i am having difficulties in making my table cells uneditable. I don't know how. The data from my table came from my database in MySQL. Please help me make my table cells uneditable because I don't want users to edit the data displayed in each cell. Thank you!

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8372799/making-jtable-cells-uneditable http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990817/how-to-make-a-jtable-non-editable http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18795791/how-to-make-individual-cell-of-a-jtable-uneditable http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24726896/how-to-make-cells-of-jtable-non-editable-but-selectable

Answer (score 0):

Hi just use in your JTable model

`public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col)
      { return false; }`

Comment: but where can I insert the codes?

Comment: tblBooks.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));

Comment: Look over [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) its oracles table tutorial/documentation and you should have in your project class which extends `AbstractTableModel` and in that class you can override method `isCellEditable(int row, int col)`.